# Синоним для словосочетания "безоговорочное принятие"

Tags: синонимы

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста, найти синоним одним словом для словосочетания "безоговорочное принятие" (в смысле- признание чего-л.недоказанного или недоказуемого)

Comment: Зачем тут синоним? Вполне нормальное сочетание. Да и синонимов что-то не получается...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, синоним был неплох для компонентного анализа

Comment: *для компонентного анализа* - это из какой дисциплины вообще? Если из языкознания, то я, признаться, весьма поверхностно представляю предмет, но зачем там синоним - и именно однословный?

Answer (score 1):

Постулирование всё же не принятие за постулат, а требование принять за постулат, за истину.

Аксиомизировать - признать за аксиому, т.е. принять без доказательств

А вот в юриспруденции есть ещё ПРЕЗУМПЦИЯ -предположение, к-рое считается истинным, пока правильность его не отвергнута (право).

Здесь тоже безоговорочное принятие предположения за истину( пока его не опровергли).

Comment: я тоже думала про "аксиому", спасибо

Comment: *Постулирование всё же не принятие за постулат, а требование принять за постулат, за истину* - 7насколько понимаю автор именно так и ставит вопрос: "безоговоррочное принятие". Ни о каком требовании "принятия за постулат" речь не идет. Вот "аксиома" здесь не приходит. Разница, если переводить с математического (и философского) языка на естественный в том, что у "аксиомы" вообще нет такого атрибута как "принятие" - она априорно принята, поэтому ни о каком "безоговорочном" принятии речь идти не может. Вот "постулат" - это да. Может быть безоговорочно принят, а может и не быть.

Comment: Другое дело, что "постулат" применимо к весьма ограниченному числу типов высказываний. Поэтому я и сказал, что синоним слабый. Но аксиома, аксиомирование - это вообще из другой оперы, если буквально рассматривать формулировку "безоговорочное принятие". Так что тут я против. Как метематик по образованию и как логик, немножко понимающий философию и алгебру высказываний.

Comment: Может, конечно, исходно у Mirych Khamitovich вообще другая сфера и другой тезаурус, не филосоыско-математический... Ну тогда я не буду вмешиваться.)))

Answer (score 0):

Есть ***постулирование*** (от *постулат*), но это весьма слабый синоним и он имеет весьма ограниченную сферу употребления не только по свыслу, но и по стилистике. Другого ничего в голову не приходит.